# run "python -m ensurepip --default-pip" but prompt me "Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (19.2.3)"

Tags: python, installation, pip, site-packages

I would like to use pip. Here I go:

```
$ python -m ensurepip --default-pip
Looking in links: /tmp/tmpd7_yb3oj
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (41.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (19.2.3)

$ pip --version
-bash: pip: command not found
```

what did i miss?

Comment: `python3.8 -m pip --version`?

Comment: `python3 -m pip --version` is also an option, for a more inclusive command.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use /usr/local/lib/pip3 install . Generally accessible pip3 is stored at /usr/bin/pip3 and same is with python3 at /usr/bin/python3.